# Reformatting negative numbers with sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed

I have a text file that contains some negative numbers except, they are formatted as:

00000012-

With the hyphen after the number.

I am processing the file using awk to reformat it into SQL insert commands and the SQL interpreter is choking on the number because the negative sign appears after the number.

Is there a regex that can move the negative sign before the number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
echo 00000012- |  sed -e 's/\([0-9]+\)\(-\)\?/\2\1/'
```

gives `-00000012`.

That is, matching two groups, the first with digits and the second with a sign, but using zero-or-more matches of *that*, and then replacing the two interchanged.

Comment: Thanks! That works and it was enough to kick some brain cells into adapting it to exactly what I needed (the number was in the middle of a longer string that I am processing with awk).

Answer (score 0):

Instead rely on the SQL to fix the problem:

```
create table #Tempt (Value VarChar(100))

Insert Into #Tempt Values(NULL)
Insert Into #Tempt Values('500.1-')
Insert Into #Tempt Values('-500.1')
Insert Into #Tempt Values('20.5')


select *, case when Value like '%-' then '-' + replace(value,'-',') else value end
 From   #Tempt
```

Then use the bulk insert to pull the values from `#Tempt` into whatever your actual table is.

---

Taken from [Bulk insert Negative Values](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1231554).

> Why do people always expect programmers to clean up goofy stuff like
>   this?

You aren't the only one...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion eyoung100. But, I am working to build scripts to process several files a day and the less places that I have to manually account for data the better.

Comment: @JayDM  I understand that fully, but as the quote relates to the issue:  Be the programmer that fixes the issue properly, not the one who writes special case scripts to account for screwy data.  Spend a day to reformat the data, and you' ll thank me, otherwise don't and everywhere someone has to write a SQL Script or a join to have it output properly, they have to find you, or your script. Secondly, SQL will process faster than your script.

Comment: Unfortunately - I am not the source of the data nor the author of it's destination. I have to deal with what I get and provide what is expected. This data is short lived (just to pass data between two systems that don't normally talk to each other). There are no other users of the data and adding steps to do on the SQL side that are in addition to the one that I have to do (the bulk insert) only adds work to me every time I process one of these files. Also, I am looking for ways to automate the steps that I am running manually...Having steps that exist across many systems makes that difficult.

Comment: Point taken, but realize you would only have to do the conversion I noted once, not on each pass, unless the side adding the data adds new numbers each transaction.

Comment: Yup - and that is exactly my situation. The data is fully replaced every time.

Answer (score 0):

With sed:

```
sed -e 's/\<\([0-9.]\+\)-/-\1/g'
```

or

```
sed -E -e 's/\<([0-9+]+)-/-\1/g'
```

With GNU awk:

```
awk '{$0=gensub(/\<([0-9.]+)-/,"-\\1","g"); print }'
```

NOTE: requires GNU awk for `gensub()` function.  Neither `sub()` nor `gsub()` support capture groups.

With perl:

```
perl -p -e 's/\b([\d.]+)-/-$1/g'
```